# Unable to locate python2 in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu-22.04

I already did `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install python2` but at the end I retrieve the same message...

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete python2
```

I added the following repository, but still no luck...

`ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`

Where can I find it? thank you

P.S:

after executing `apt update`

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Se pueden actualizar 13 paquetes. Ejecute «apt list --upgradable» para verlos.
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete python2
```

Comment: it should just be in your repo without the need to install additional repositories. What did you get after `apt update` any errors?

Comment: No what I meant is when you run `sudo apt update` do you get any errors during this step :)

Comment: No errors sir... and yes I have python 3 installed

Comment: what happens if you do `apt search python` is it listed ?

Comment: appeared a lot, i tried as well with python2, and it shows python2.7-minimal, but I tried to install and it says it is not available

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250522/discussion-between-m-mariscal-and-lars-nielsen).

Comment: Sorry had to go to a meeting. Good that you solved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Remove everything and paste:

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
```

and then:

```
sudo apt update
```